# ¿Cómo utilizar la etiqueta <b> con una fuente agregada en TCPDF?

Tags: php, html, tcpdf

Estoy creando un documento con la librería TCPDF y agregue una nueva fuente, pero al utilizar la nueva fuente no me funciona la etiqueta  y si quito la fuente si funciona, quiero saber si hay que agregar algo al archivo de la fuente para que funcione la etiqueta.

```
$pdf->SetFont('graphiklight', '', 10.5);
```

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="font-size:16px; border: none"><b>Texto de prueba</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center" style="font-size:16px; border: none">Texto de prueba</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar

```
<strong></strong>
```